# Suggestions for SCORM player + API or Library in Java and player in Flash

Tags: java, api, scorm, scorm2004

I'm hoping I can be guided in the right direction.

I have been asked to help with a web eTraining software.  Basically videos, and questions alternating.  A request has come up to be able to handle and play SCORM courses.

I have done some reading and gotten familiar with how it works, and discovered some wonderful and affordable SCORM course creation software.

The question I'm stuck with is this:  I need a Java (.NET is 2nd choice and okay too) library for SCORM integration that I can wrap a Flash based SCORM player around (which I also need to find)

Apologies in advance if I missed somewhere on here that already has it.  I'm looking for names, and hopefully some experiences/opinions/what to look out for in such a library/API.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try open source project http://code.google.com/p/celine-scorm/ I have no experience with it, I just know it's actively developed.

Answer (score 2):

Our company, Rustici Software, offers a product called the [SCORM Engine](http://www.scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-engine/) that is exactly what you are looking for. It is a SCORM player that can easily be integrated into any system. The SCORM Engine is available in both Java and .Net. We also offer a hosted version called the [SCORM Cloud](http://www.scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud/) that is even easier to integrate and get started with.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your comment.  It's helpful to see the information you have posted.  Is the fee you have listed for the product itself, or includes the integration work as well?

Comment: The SCORM Engine's implementation fee includes the integration work. The SCORM Cloud is designed so you can integrate it yourself. Email me at mike at scorm dot com if you want to chat some more.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Since there's no other answer I'll accept this one for the time being.  Would love to see any other projects that have the full scorm player in Flash.

Answer (score 0):

For the Flash side of things, you could check out:

http://pipwerks.com/2008/04/27/how-to-add-basic-scorm-code-to-a-flash-movie/

for a complete tutorial and opensource code on integrating Scorm 1.2 and 2004 into your Flash player/engine.